# Inexplicable Mathematica7 DumpSave[] problem

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a very large array of floating point image data:

```
In[25]:= Dimensions[daylightImgd]
Out[25]= {18, 2002, 2989}

In[26]:= daylightImgd[[1, 1]][[1 ;; 10]]

Out[26]= {0.0122293, 0.0104803, 0.0103955, 0.0115533, 0.0118063, \
0.0120648, 0.0122957, 0.011398, 0.0117426, 0.0119997}
```

I can save this whole image array to disk successfully using DumpSave a la:

```
DumpSave["thisWorks.mx", daylightImgd]
```

Dumping this giant (861 meg file) takes less than 10 seconds.  If I downsample these images, a la:

```
downsample[image_, f_] := Module[{w, h}, h = Dimensions[image][[1]];
  w = Dimensions[image][[2]];
  Table[image[[i, j]], {i, 1, h, f}, {j, 1, w, f}]]

In[26]:= daylightImgdDown = downsample[#, 4] & /@ daylightImgd;
In[27]:= Dimensions[daylightImgdDown]
Out[27]= {18, 500, 748}

In[28]:= daylightImgdDown[[1, 1]][[1 ;; 10]]

Out[28]= {0.0122293, 0.0118063, 0.0117426, 0.0119349, 0.0109443, \
0.0121632, 0.0121304, 0.00681408, 0.0101728, 0.00603242}
```

Then suddenly I can't dumpsave anymore; the thing hangs and spins forever -- or at least for many minutes, till I kill it, and maxes CPU:

```
In[31]:= DumpSave["broken.mx", daylightImgdDown];    (* Hangs forever *)
```

So far as I can determine, everything is as it should be: the downsampled images have the right dimensions; you can plot them via ArrayPlot and everything looks great; manually listing the first row looks fine.  Everything, in short, appears the same as with the non-down-sampled images, yet on the much smaller dataset DumpSave hangs.

Help?

**UPDATE: Comments on Michael's answer**

Wow.  Thank you for the extremely thorough answer, which not only answered my question but taught me a bunch of peripheral stuff, too.

For your reference, the issue of packed-ness was a little trickier than just replacing my downsample[] with one of yours.  Since the array I was trying to dump is an array of 18 images - a 3d array, in other words - and since I'm applying the downsampling via the Map operator, the packed-ness of the 3d array is false (according to PackedArrayQ) using either of your downsample rewrites.

However, if I take the output of those applications, and then pack the resultant 3d array, *then* the whole 3d array is packed, and *only then* can I DumpSave it.  Weirdly, though, this final process of packing, while necessary for a successful DumpSave, barely seems to alter the size, as reported by ByteCount.  Maybe this is easier in code:

```
In[42]:= downsample3[image_, f_] := 
 Module[{w, h}, h = Dimensions[image][[1]];
  w = Dimensions[image][[2]];
  Developer`ToPackedArray@Table[image[[i, j]], {i, 1, h, f}, {j, 1, w, f}]]

In[43]:= daylightImgdDown = downsample3[#, downsampleSize] & /@ daylightImgd;
In[44]:= ByteCount[daylightImgdDown]
Out[44]= 53966192

In[45]:= Developer`PackedArrayQ[daylightImgdDown]
Out[45]= False

In[46]:= dd = Developer`ToPackedArray[daylightImgdDown];
In[47]:= Developer`PackedArrayQ[dd]
Out[47]= True

In[48]:= ByteCount[dd]
Out[48]= 53963844

In[49]:= DumpSave["daylightImgdDown.mx", dd]; (* works now! *)
```

Again, thanks very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without the actual data, an educated guess is that the reason the large array `DumpSave`s quickly is because it is a so-called "packed array", that is, an array of machine-sized floating point numbers that has a very efficient representation in Mathematica. Your `downsample` function (due to the use of `Table`) does not return a packed array, which is much larger in memory, potentially larger than even the original array after being downsampled 4X. [`ByteCount`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ByteCount.html) might be illustrative there.

You can check for packed-array-ness with [`PackedArrayQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Developer/ref/PackedArrayQ.html) and attempt to pack an unpacked array with [`ToPackedArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Developer/ref/ToPackedArray.html), both found in the `Developer` context.

There are two solutions, if my guess is correct. One is to use `ToPackedArray` as shown:

```
downsample[image_, f_] := Module[{w, h}, h = Dimensions[image][[1]];
  w = Dimensions[image][[2]];
  Developer`ToPackedArray@Table[image[[i, j]], {i, 1, h, f}, {j, 1, w, f}]]
```

Even better is to simply replace your use of `Table` with `Take`, which should return a packed array in this case, and as an added bonus be a lot faster than using `Table`.

```
downsample[image_, f_] := Take[image, {1,-1,f}, {1,-1,f}]
```

You might also be interested in all the new [image processing functionality](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/ImageProcessing.html) in Mathematica 7.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Wow, nice answer!  Interested to hear if this solves the asker's problem.